# Stops per condition on Login?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, if-statement

I am new to C# so my problem is at Login Form.

If my user class is anything other than "admin" every time I hit the submit button it will bring me back to login form. So my statements stops when the condition is not true I'm guessing. here is my code.

--------Edit 
Sorry about my newbie limitations 
here is what I have:
 A sql table with usernames and roles 
depending on what role they have the user will load a different form

```
// Compare strings
 private bool CompareStrings(string string1, string string2)
    {
        return String.Compare(string1, string2, true, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) == 0 ? true : false;
    }




// button on Login form    
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlConnection UGIcon = new SqlConnection();
            UGIcon.ConnectionString = "Data Source=BVSQL; Initial Catalog=BV1;user id=jose; password=jones6;";

            UGIcon.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT ISNULL(bvuser, '') AS stUsername, ISNULL(bvpassword,'') AS stPassword, ISNULL(bvclass, '') AS stRole FROM BVusertable WHERE bvuser='" + textBox1.Text + "' and bvpassword='" + textBox2.Text + "'", UGIcon);
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            string userText = textBox1.Text;
            string passText = textBox2.Text;
            //string stRole = "admin";

            dr.Read();
            {
                if
                   (this.CompareStrings(dr["stUsername"].ToString(), userText) &&
                    this.CompareStrings(dr["stPassword"].ToString(), passText)
                    )
                {
                    if (this.CompareStrings(dr["stRole"].ToString(), "admin"))
                    {
                        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
                    }
                    else if (this.CompareStrings(dr["stRole"].ToString(), "user"))
                    {
                        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.No;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    //MessageBox.Show("Error");
                }
            }
            dr.Close();
            UGIcon.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Login Falied");
        }
    }
```

here is the Programs.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace BV_SOFT
{
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Loginf fLogin = new Loginf();
        if (fLogin.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Application.Run(new Home2());
        }
        else
        if (fLogin.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.No)
        {
            Application.Run(new Home3());
        }
        else
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }
```

Comment: What is in the `this.CompareStrings` method? Why not just do `==` instead of calling that method?

Comment: @sparky68967 - it might do a case insensitive comparison (for example).

Comment: @ChrisF that might be ok for user names, but I wouldn't recommend that for passwords.

Comment: String.compare has an option for that - no need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @sparky68967 - that's true. I missed that usage. However, I don't think it's relevant for the question.

Answer (score 2):

You're calling ShowDialog twice. Try this:

```
Loginf fLogin = new Loginf();
DialogResult result = fLogin.ShowDialog();
if (result == DialogResult.OK)
{
    Application.Run(new Home2());
}
else if (result == DialogResult.No)
{
    Application.Run(new Home3());
}
else
{
    Application.Exit();
}
```

Calling `ShowDialog` twice will show the form twice. Using this will only show it once. In your code, if the role is not "admin" then the else block is executed, and it calls `ShowDialog` *again* which will show the form *again*, which isn't what you want. Show the form once, store the result, and do your checking on the stored result.

Answer (score 1):

You are only setting the `DialogResult` to `OK` when the user has the "admin" role.

In all other cases except when the role is "user" you are leaving the result unset. This will mean that the form won't be dismissed.

Without knowing what your logic is I can't suggest what it should be.